# CSS Style for Table

Tags: html, css

I have a Table like below
 I wanna to add Left property to odd Columns.

```
   <table id="tblTopcontrols">
            <tr>
                <td>
                </td>
                <td>
                </td>
                <td>
                </td>
                <td>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

I want to wrtie a Style for this table to adding these properties to this table.

```
    <table id="tblTopcontrols">
                <tr>
                    <td align=left>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td align=left>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try use a css3 selector such as [:nth-child()](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/nthchild.html)

http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/

For example:

```
#tblTopcontrols td:nth-child(odd)
{
    text-align: left;
}
```

If you are worried about compatibility, jquery allows css3 style selectors even on browsers which do not directly support css3.

You can then do something like:

```
//add the css class named "someAlignLeftClass" to all odd td elements of 
// the table with the id 'tblTopcontrols':
$("#tblTopcontrols td:nth-child(odd)").addClass("someAlignLeftClass");
```

And then declare the class itself in CSS:

```
.someAlignLeftClass
{
    text-align: left;
}
```

Sure its useful if you use jquery, but most sites do these days.  It saves manually going through each td and editing the html to add a class.  Maybe you have a lot of these types of tables...

Answer (score 6):

```
<table id="tblTopcontrols">
            <tr>
                <td class="odd"></td>
                <td></td>
                <td class="odd"></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
</table>
```

and just apply a style like `text-align:left` for the `#tblTopcontrols td.odd` class

Answer (score 5):

You can't apply HTML attributes with CSS, but for your case of left-aligning your text, you can either use CSS3'S `:nth-child()`:

```
#tblTopcontrols td:nth-child(odd) { text-align: left; }
```

Or if you need better browser compatibility, go with [danip's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5659836/css-style-for-table/5659874#5659874).